# Where is J.A.R.V.I.S physically located?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-3

To me J.A.R.V.I.S seems to be a self aware AI but even then he would need hardware to run on. After seeing Iron Man 3 I am confused as to where he is actually stored. Tony's mansion is destroyed but he was still with Tony and shuts down after the Mark XLII crashes in Tennessee.

However for J.A.R.V.I.S to be able to control the Iron Man Legion wouldn't he need to be centralized at some location and i would assume, even with Tony's genius, there would be a lot of hardware involved (unless magic was used, but I don't think Tony's encounter with Thor would be enough to add magic to J.A.R.V.I.S after Avengers). So I am wondering, where is J.A.R.V.I.S located?

NOTE: if it makes a difference, I am mainly asking about the Movie continuity.

Comment: In Iron Man 1, I think he specifically said he's been "uploaded to the suit's computer" or some such, just before the Mark II test.  That would indicate that he can move, so there could be several servers at several houses and Stark Industries properties that can support him.

Comment: J.A.R.V.I.S is a fictional disembodied, self-aware synthetic intelligence which features centrally in the Iron Man franchise and serves as the franchise's secondary protagonist.

Rarely depicted visually in any of the Iron Man media, J.A.R.V.I.S gained self-awareness after it had spread into millions of computer servers all across the earth.

Comment: @MajorStackings Is that a quote?  Do you have a source, either for the quote or the idea of a planet-spanning JARVIS?

Comment: @Nerrolken Skynet wiki...

Comment: Nice question. I have often wondered this myself...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to film's [official Novelisation](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Iron-Man-Peter-David/dp/034550609X), J.A.R.V.I.S. is the operating system for Tony's home computer, however, when he goes remote (and uses the Iron Man suits) it downloads itself into **the suit's own computer systems**:

> ***He pressed a button on a lab console and downloaded Jarvis’s program
>   into the suit’s computer system.*** The armor’s heads-up display flashed
>   to life. “Ready?” Tony said. “Three… two… one…” The lift jets in the
>   suit’s boots fired up. “Handles like a dream,” he said.

This is backed up by the film's original script'

> **Tony :** *Jarvis, are you there?*
>   **JARVIS :** *At your service, sir.*
>   **Tony :** *Engage Heads Up Display.*
>   **JARVIS :** *Check.*
>   **Tony :** *Import all preferences from home interface.*
>   **JARVIS :** *Will do, sir.*
>   **Tony :** *All right, what do you say?*
>   **JARVIS :** ***I have indeed been uploaded, sir.*** We're online and ready.

Comment: Alright, I'm calling it.  Richard isn't a person, it's a living database of film/tv novelizations.  The evidence is overwhelming.

Comment: @Nerrolken - I also quoted the script. I'm a bit bored of slamming people's questions with the novelisations.

Comment: @Nerrolken - So who wants to post the question "Where is Richard's servers physically located"?

Comment: @SystemDown Don't you mean "R.I.C.H.A.R.D."?

Comment: @systemdown - I'm tempted to ask a question about whether people like novelisation answers

Comment: I Always thought it was more like a remote session to the suit's hardware....

Comment: @ash_k29 - I'll try to answer if JARVIS is a singular consciousness

Comment: Of course then you have to wonder where exactly JARVIS went at the end of Iron Man III when Tony tells him to blow all the remaining suits.

Comment: @gnovice JARVIS is computer code. When Tony invoked House Party Protocol in IM3 it seems like each suit had a copy of JARVIS... so I'm OK with there being a master copy elsewhere that Tony can spin up instances from. That master copy was consumed in the creation of Vision. I figure Tony didn't restore a backup out of sentiment after that, and created FRIDAY to replace his old friend.